# How toss Vue's transpiling to es5

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

The Vue cli typically transpiles es6 to es5 with babel and webpack.

Is there a Vue cli built template or template option that just transforms the .vue files correctly but does not run babel to convert the code to es5? And does not bundle?

My goal is to simply transpile the .vue files and I'll do the rest to integrate the results into my es6 + modules workflow.

Note: I tried using the "simple" cli template but couldn't find documentation on how to use it.

Comment: if you are using `simple cli` template then you can't use `.vue` extension. It doesn't require build tools or Node.js... Simply Refer Vue Docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ for coding

Comment: If you want to _"simply transpile the .vue files"_ then you are looking for [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader)